# Rails-How to use MiniTest's Teardown Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, teardown

I have been looking around the internet for a long, frustrating, while, and I'm still quite confused as to what the purpose of the `teardown()` method is in MiniTest and how it should be used.

The basic gist I have is that it is 1-run after each test, and 2-undoes things that were done during the test in order to allow future tests to run in a clean environment.

However, I am unclear on the nature of things it needs to undo: Does it need to empty the DB? Reset class variables? etc.

I am also unclear on whether the method is supposed to be explicitly filled out or not. I have found many examples where `teardown()` is completely left out of the example.

(My best guess is that there is a super-method `teardown` that runs automatically and takes care of certain things. That would explain why it is often left out, and would also explain why some things are reset in a given `teardown()` method and some aren't. But I still don't know which things are and which aren't.)

In short:

**Does teardown need to be explicitly created? In what circumstances would it need to be overwritten and in which wouldn't it be?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest answer is that you use `#teardown` in every test but you don't need to worry about it. Similar to the Rails lifecycle, there is a Minitest lifecycle. There are hooks to inject logic and behavior to be used by your tests. The main one in Rails tests is the database transaction. Each test that uses `ActiveSupport::TestCase` runs in a database transaction. The flow is like this:

1. Create the database transaction (`Minitest::Test#setup`)
2. Run your test method (`MyTest#test_something`)
3. Rollback the database transaction (`Minitest::Test#teardown`)

It is somewhat common for folks to use `#setup` to create objects for use in tests. After the test method completes the test object is garbage collected, so most folks don't use `#teardown` to clean up after the test. Because of this `#teardown` is typically a more advanced feature that you don't normally use when writing tests. I see it used much more often in testing libraries that enhance Minitest.

But there are times I do use `#teardown` in my tests. Here is an example of when I might use it.

```
require "minitest/autorun"

class Foo
  def initialize namer
    @namer = namer
  end
  def name
    @namer.name
  end
end

class FooTest < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @namer_mock = Minitest::Mock.new
    @namer_mock.expect :name, "foo"
    @foo = Foo.new @namer_mock
  end

  def test_name
    assert_equal "foo", @foo.name
  end

  def teardown
    @namer_mock.verify
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this a correct summary (just want to make sure I understand)? Basically, `#teardown` is NOT needed to empty the database or destroy the instances that were created during the test. It IS needed (or could be, at least) if you want to do something more advanced after the tests are run; something beyond just ensuring the DB is empty and the instances are gone. That right?